# onBackPressed doesn't play the defined animation?

Tags: android

**Update:**

I figured out that the reason was that the @Override method itself was misconstrued. Although this is a duplicate question the answer is still available for StackOverflow members to use.

In your activity you must declare the @Override as follows:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.disappear, R.anim.appear);
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
```

Hope that clears up any discrepancy.

Comment: What button are you referring to? Are you referring to the Android hardware back button or the back button in the title bar specific to your app?

Comment: Did you also override the onBackPressed() method in `Activity2`?

Comment: **possible duplicate request mod deletion**

Comment: @Goooooogle: Don't delete question bodies. Duplicates help to find original questions if they are present and have slightly different wording.

Comment: @Goooooogle: [Read on duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)